# Groovy String return type with instantiation

Tags: groovy

This is my class where I am reading an properties file there are two files Config.groovy where I have the method and Call.groovy where I am calling the method from config and expecting an return.

Config.groovy

```
class Config
{

public  methodParse  { 

    Properties properties = new Properties()

    File propertiesFile = new File('src/main/resources/application.properties')
    propertiesFile.withInputStream 
        {
            properties.load(it)
        }

    String value = properties."$name"
    return value
    }
}
```

load.groovy

```
 def config = new Config ()
 config.methodParse "environments.local.logfile"
 println (config.methodParse());
```

How do I have load.groovy pass an parameter and then print what is received?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the syntax errors
You could try something like

```
    class Config
    {

        public String methodParse (String name) 
        {

            Properties properties = new Properties()

            File propertiesFile = new File('src/main/resources/application.properties')
            propertiesFile.withInputStream 
            {
                properties.load(it)
            }

            String value = properties."$name"
            return value
        }
    }

    def config = new Config ()
     the_value =config.methodParse("environments.local.logfile")
     println (conf_value);
```

Comment: This is what i get when i run that Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: retun for class:

Answer (score 0):

What if I understand you correctly.

```
class Config {
    public methodParse(String name) {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        File propertiesFile = new File('src/main/resources/application.properties')
        propertiesFile.withInputStream {
            properties.load(it)
        }
        properties."$name"
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
    def config = new Config ()
    config.methodParse "environments.local.logfile"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it this is what I did

def config = new Config ()
     String conf_value = config.methodParse("environments.local.logfile")
     println conf_value